# Imported users directly in the database not showing in Admin UI Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I imported a csv file to my Keycloak postgresql database in the `user_entity` table and all my users from a legacy system seem to be inserted correctly. But they are not showing up in the Admin UI.

Is there any other configuration I need to adjust for?

Comment: Did you check that the users belong to the realm ?